# HTML select tag autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got some select tag as follows:

```
<select id="fruits">
   <option value="1">Apple</option>
   <option value="2">Banana</option>
   <option value="3">Orange</option>
   <option value="4">Grapes</option>
   <option value="5">Ginger</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is, whenever the user focus on the `select`, and he's clicking on the key "`G`" in his keyboard, the option "`Grapes`" will be automatically selected, and when he presses "`G`" once again, "`Ginger`" will be selected and so on.

I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: this already happens for select boxes in IE and Chrome, not sure about firefox as i dont have it installed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, If you want to add Auto Complete functionality to your html select element then there is nothing better than selectize.js

All you need to do is either include its css and js file in your project or you can use cdns.

Go to Selectize website [here](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the default action of drop down(select control). You have to do zero effort to achieve it.

try this `JSbin`.. there is a select box and when user first presses `g` on the keyboard `grapes is selected` and on second `ginger is selected`

http://jsbin.com/UYeZaPA/1/edit

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes.

Comment: But sometimes, it just doesn't work. I can press the key for over 10 times, and it doesn't jump to the instance with that starting letter

Comment: @kfirba : you have to click on the drop down before playing with letters using key board

Comment: @Amith I know that. But whenever I choose to pick another letter, it get stuck and doesnt work properly for some reason

Comment: @Amith happens constantly for me :/

Comment: @kfirba Just press escape before choosing another letter.

Comment: @mc10 unfortunately, it doesnt really fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gU4a5/)

What you are asking for is the default functionality of drop-down-list.

if you want to search the drop-down-list you can try this plugin.

[jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin Demo](http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/)

[**DEMO - with your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/sf42V/9/)

```
$('#fruits').searchable();
```

you can also try [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VeLKW/227/)

Comment: [jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin Demo](http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/) > *This site can’t be reached `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`*