# Searching a HTML <select> List with a Large Number of Entries

Tags: html, html-select

I have a similar question to the one asked here.

[HTML select tag autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302036/html-select-tag-autocomplete)

A  list on a website I use had a large (~20,000) number of entries. So when I highlight an option and start typing to find an entry I'm looking for, the browser (Chrome) can't find the option quickly enough. If I tried to find an entry, for example, called 'Apple', I would begin typing the word and the list would highlight an entry beginning with 'A', then another entry beginning with 'P' and so on. It is able to find strings of characters (eg, an entry beginning with 'Ap') but only if I type at a very specific speed.

My question is, as a user, are there any settings, browser or otherwise, that I could access to allow me to search this list? Perhaps to change the speed I need to type in order to search for strings of characters. In Chrome's settings (and advanced settings), there appear to be no settings related to this.

Thanks.

Comment: i use this https://select2.github.io/ it very usefull for me. It have ajax support for serverside easy. May be help

Answer (score 0):

**As a user, there's not much that can be done**. You don't have access to the underlying data structures of the `<select>` element, so the browser has to search through the `<option>`s one at a time.

**As a developer, the trick is to not search the `<select>` box**. Instead, use it as the raw data to build a searchable data structure when the box first loads, and then run your searches on that instead. The result of a search should contain the appropriate index into the `<select>` box, and then you just select that.

**A trie (not to be confused with a binary search tree) might work well for something like this**. At each node in the trie, you store the index of the first `<option>` element whose prefix matches the string up to that point. Then you branch off to child nodes corresponding to the next character in the string. John Resig, of jQuery fame, did some work with [JavaScript tries](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) a few years ago. He was using it on a text dictionary, but it should be adaptable to something like this.