# Autocomplete in select tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have this select tag which is as follows:

```
<select id ="fruits">
<option value="1">Grapes</option>
<option value="2">Ginger</option>
<option value="3">Guava</option>
<option value="4">Mango</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is, whenever the user focus on the select, and he's clicking on the key "G" in his keyboard, the option "Grapes" will be automatically selected, and when he presses "u" after that, "Guava" will be selected and so on. I know that this can be done by using various jquery plugin but I do not want to use a jquery plugin.
How can I do this using only javascript?

There is a similar question posted but it doesnot answer my problem
[HTML select tag autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302036/html-select-tag-autocomplete)

I am a beginner in javascript and jquery so any help will be great

Comment: Modern browsers already do it. You don't need to use javascript or anything else.

Comment: Your list is very small - so q1 - why?, q2) why not use jquery trust me it's the way, used loads over the internet if you aim to make a career out of javascript, it will come up best to start now.

Comment: @osny netto, yeah if you press g it go's to the next 'g', if you press again it will go to the next one. There is something in this. It's what the user expects and what they have learnt from using the internet. Changing that behavior is going to be like 'what!' from the users perspective. - read some usability guides and they will prob tell you the same.

Comment: @RichardHousham, I have to specifically do using javascript even jquery is fine but no plugins like autocomplete or chosen,etc. And this list is just a small example I have a large list of like 1000 entries